# Theme comment callback results nothing

Tags: themes, comments, comments-template

I made theme and now im finally editing the look of wp_list_comments. I made function, wrote callback link to arguments and tried it. It returns nothing - only elements hard coded in comments.php are displayed (that are just bones for that list...) Ive tried very much ways and nothing worked;
comments.php: `wp_list_comments(array('callback'=>'ksgcomcall')); ?>`
functions.php:

```
<?php 
function ksgcomcall($comment, $args, $depth){
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;

    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <article id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment">

            <div class="comment-content"><?php comment_text(); ?></div>

            <p><?php echo "Comment authors age: ".get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'age', true ); ?></p>

            <div class="reply">
                <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'reply_text' => __( 'Reply <span>&darr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ), 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
            </div>
        </article>
    </li>
    <?php
}
?> - its just copy of example from codex..
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Hmm... Time for dumb double checks. Is your function is getting called at all (do something drastic like `die()` in it)? Is the `wp_list_comments()` being called from the place you expect (and not different template file or something) ?

Comment: Theres no call for die or something like that. The function is called only by callback attr from comments.php and the function is in functions_fc.php added to functions.php by get template part. Every other functions from that file works, only this one not. :( I dont know its not Wordpress 3.5.2

Comment: Is there anybody who knows how to solve? It's very bad for me... Please